# How to test REST api in laravel having dynamic URI using phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to test my REST API written in laravel faramework using phpunit.

Here is my **api.php** file code

```
Route::group([
  'middleware' => ['cors','db.select'],
  'prefix'     => 'v1/{database}',
], function() {
    Route::resource('test-beds', 'TestBedController');
});
```

where **cors middleware** allows to send Cross-Origin Resource Sharing and **db.select middleware** is created by me which removes the `{database}` variable from routes.

In my **TestBedController** if I don't send **id field** with post method it gives response with HTTP status code 422. To validate that I've written following code.

Here is my **TestBedApiTest.php** file

```
class TestBedApiTest extends TestCase {

  public function testRequiresId() {
    // I tried by adding and removing following line but no luck
    $this->WithoutMiddleware();
    $this->json('POST', 'test-beds')->assertResponseStatus(422);
  }
}
```

But it's returning me **404** which is most probably because it's unable to find route **test-beds**. I tried following codes but no luck

```
 $this->json('POST', 'v1/db1/test-beds')->assertResponseStatus(422);

 $this->json('POST', 'api/v1/db1/test-beds')->assertResponseStatus(422);

 $this->json('POST', 'api/v1/test-beds')->assertResponseStatus(422);

 $this->json('POST', 'v1/{database}/test-beds')->assertResponseStatus(422);
```

Answer (score -1):

Testing of API is good idea , by the using of PHP unit & guzzle 
step 1 download PHP unit & guzzle that library help us to make requests to the API.
you install both composer by command like

```
$ composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:^6.1 phpunit/phpunit:^5.0
```

by installing that library you include into `autoload.php`

then after develop test class in api and then run the function name `setup()`
and then test you api by implement your function.